# What is QT analog of .NET User settings, is it similar in use?

Tags: c++, .net, qt

I wonder what is QT analog of this [.NET feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx) that would esely allow for example to [save some user imputed value into TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704516/how-to-save-user-imputed-value-in-textbox-wpf-xaml)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple flat file with key-value format, you can use [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qsettings.html)