# Set default text in textBox on button click

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm wondering how to set default text in textBox on button click. So when the users closes the form and open it again the text in textBoxes would stay. Even if he closes the entire app. I tried this code below, but I think my solution is way far from the working one. Thank you so much for your time.

```
private void btn_savetext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
    this.textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text;
    this.textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text;
    this.textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the value user entered or you want to reset it to default value?

Comment: @HarisHasan Thanks for your time. I would like to keep that value.

Comment: question is not clear?

Comment: do you mean an entry value that needs to be remembered?

Comment: @Marek You can use Session to remember the value mate

Comment: @bew you are absolutly right. But without using database is it possible?

Comment: You can write those values to file (manually or via serialization) and the load them from file when you need those values

Comment: @Marek anything else you would like me to add to my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what the default text is?

If it is going to be the same value each time then you can set the text property in the design view, so that value will be in the textbox each time.

If you want the textbox to save the value that the user has put in, then you would need to look into a way to store the information. Possible ways you could do this would be:

1. Set up a SQL data with an insert/update procedure, then set up the textbox to load the saved value from the SQL table each time the form is loaded.
2. Set up XAML, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704516/how-to-save-user-imputed-value-in-textbox-wpf-xaml) to guide yourself through that. (this option would probably be preferred as setting up a SQL data table to store one value may be a bit extreme for you).
3. If you want to look into sessions then I would advise looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
4. From Nikita's comment you could save the value to a .txt document also, again this probably won't be preferred but it is a good thing to learn in the future. To do this you will want to look into [filewriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [streamwriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx). The option is yours, you can either replace the file each time, or update the existing file to add the new value.

Why your code won't work:

```
 this.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
 this.textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text;
 this.textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text;
 this.textBox4.Text = textBox4.Text;
```

Unfortunately this won't save the text, and when the UI is closed/re-opened you are just setting the values to equal each other, and as it wouldn't have saved, this would mean you are setting them both to equal null.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a web application you could also write the values to be saved inside of a cookie. Although it won't be persisted as strongly as writing out your own custom file. :)