# How do I persist the value of the Textbox Text property of a user control when switching from one view to another?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Learning C#, specifically WPF, and the MVVM framework. I'm creating a basic project that presents a MainWindow with a contentcontrol binding. Straightforward.

I have 2 views, each with a textbox. I have 2 buttons on the MainWindow, each allow me to toggle between views. However, when I enter data in a textbox, switch views, and come back, the data is gone. How can I persist that data to be consumed later?

Relevant code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestDataRetention.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDataRetention"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:TestDataRetention.Views"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TestDataRetention.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:View1ViewModel}">
            <views:View1View DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:View2ViewModel}">
            <views:View2View DataContext="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button x:Name="View1Button" Margin="10" Width="80" Content="View1" Click="View1Button_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="View2Button" Margin="10" Width="80" Content="View2" Click="View2Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ContentControl x:Name="Content" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using TestDataRetention.ViewModels;

namespace TestDataRetention
{
    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void View1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new View1ViewModel();
        }

        private void View2Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = new View2ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

View1View.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestDataRetention.Views.View1View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDataRetention.Views"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestDataRetention.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             FontSize="24"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:View1ViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="AliceBlue">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Enter View1 Stuff"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="View1TextBox" Width="400" Height="50" Text="{Binding View1Words}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

View1View.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using TestDataRetention.ViewModels;

namespace TestDataRetention.Views
{
    public partial class View1View : UserControl
    {
        public View1View()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new View1ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

View2 is obviously the same as View1 but with corresponding variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there might also be a way to just have wpf cache it for you, you can just as easily save it properly and then have the input available at will.

Look here for two methods on how to:

[How to save user inputed value in TextBox? (WPF, XAML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704516/how-to-save-user-inputed-value-in-textbox-wpf-xaml)

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the info. I manipulated the settings file just fine. Now the problem I have is that the buttons reside in MainWindow.cs, so how do I write to the settings file a property from a user control that is not directly available inn MainWindow.cs upon click of a button?

Comment: Like M. Elghamry said, you are creating a new object upon each button click which makes this all rather tedious. You need to call Settings.Default.Save() before the old object is destroyed in order to save the information, even with a two way binding.

Comment: Thanks. I added all of the variables needed in the settings.settings file, and ensured the save method is called. This got me over the hump! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

At quick glance, you create `new` ViewModel each time your button is clicked, this will always create new ViewModel for your `DataContext` not using the original one.

Also this snippet from your code will create `new` ViewModel for your Control's DataContext regardless of the one the parent control has:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:View1ViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

And I am not sure how you use your `DataTemplate` here:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:View1ViewModel}">
    <views:View1View DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:View2ViewModel}">
    <views:View2View DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

But generally, as a guidance for you to model your MVVM project, always keep in mind that XAML code is translated to C# while compiling. So when writing something like `<vm:View1ViewModel/>` you actually do `new View1ViewModel()`.

So for you to use the DataContext your control inherited from its parent, you just use `<UserControl DataContext="{binding}"` for your UserControl.

And for your button click, you have to keep a pointer for your previously created ViewModel and assign it to the DataContext when needed, I suggest you to create these ViewModels only when needed to minimize memory consumption in large applications, like:

```
private View1ViewModel m_View1VM = null;
private void View1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (m_View1VM is null)
        m_View1VM = new View1ViewModel();
    this.DataContext = m_View1VM;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I get around calling a new ViewModel every time? Or, can I save the properties to memory and have them rebuild the view? Also, to answer the remark regarding how I use the DataTemplates, if I comment that section out and run the program, when I click the buttons it only presents a string in the Content Control of the path to the ViewModel. I was taught that was needed there. Also, regarding the this.DataContext vs. <vm:View1ViewModel/>, isn't that just a matter of preference?

Comment: You are welcome!, please note that I corrected the last code snippet. And I see your point now for using the DataTemplate. Good Luck!

Comment: Regarding the difference between `<vm:View1ViewModel/>` and `this.DataContext`, the point here is that you need to access the DataContext your control got from its parent, `<vm:View1ViewModel/>` will create new ViewModel, and thus you won't be able to reach the data saved to the original created ViewModel provided in the Button Click. And after revising the code and your usage for the `DataTemplate`, you don't need `<UserControl DataContext="{binding}"` as your DataTemplate assigns that already.

Comment: For getting around creating new ViewModel every time, you will note that in the last code snippet, the m_View1VM is in the global space of your class not within the method, so, when you call Button Click, the method will check if the ViewModel has been created before, if not, create new one, if created, then use it.